# Make a full screen cube slider using pure html css

Tags: html, css, slider, css-transforms, slide

I have been trying to create a full screen cube slider i have taken this example from codepen [example](https://codepen.io/fornyhucker/pen/krnBE)

```css
.three-d-container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 230px;
}

.three-d-cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ( -450px);
}

.three-d-cube .three-d-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.three-d-cube .three-d-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX( 180deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY( -90deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateX( -90deg) translateZ( 450px);
}

.a:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateY( 0deg);
}

.b:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateX( -180deg);
}

.c:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateY( -90deg);
}

.d:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateY( 90deg);
}

.e:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateX( -90deg);
}

.f:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: translateZ( -450px) rotateX( 90deg);
}

.three-d-bullet {
  margin: 850px 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.three-d-bullet:first-child {
  margin: 850px 10px 0 88px;
}
```

```html
<section class="three-d-container">
  <input type="radio" checked class="three-d-bullet a" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet b" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet c" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet d" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet e" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet f" name="three-d">
  <div class="three-d-cube">
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/1" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/2" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/3" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/4" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/5" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/6" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Above i provide my modified code which i tried so far. If i increase the width of cube section the whole cube system is broken but i need to make a full screen width cube slider.
any help would be very appreciable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want this??.. i will add description once you accept it. thanks

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font: 24px Helvetica, Arial, serif;
}
.creds {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, serif;
}
.creds a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
.three-d-container{
margin:30px auto;
width:600px;
height:600px;
border-radius: 3px;
position:relative;
-webkit-perspective:1000px;
   -moz-perspective:1000px;
    -ms-perspective:1000px;
     -o-perspective:1000px;
        perspective:1000px;
}
.three-d-cube{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
   -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 1s;
     -o-transition:     -o-transform 1s;
        transition:        transform 1s;
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px );
        transform:translateZ( -150px );
}
.three-d-cube .three-d-item{
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
margin:0;
position:absolute;
}
.three-d-cube .three-d-item img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
margin:0;
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(1){
-webkit-transform:rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(2){
-webkit-transform:rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(3){
-webkit-transform:rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(4){
-webkit-transform:rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(5){
-webkit-transform:rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.three-d-item:nth-child(6){
-webkit-transform:rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
   -moz-transform:rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
    -ms-transform:rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
     -o-transform:rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
        transform:rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 300px );
}
.a:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(    0deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(    0deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(    0deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(    0deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(    0deg );
}
.b:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX( -180deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX( -180deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX( -180deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX( -180deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX( -180deg );
}
.c:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
}
.d:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(   90deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(   90deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(   90deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(   90deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateY(   90deg );
}
.e:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
}
.f:checked ~ .three-d-cube{
-webkit-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(   90deg );
   -moz-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(   90deg );
    -ms-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(   90deg );
     -o-transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(   90deg );
        transform:translateZ( -150px ) rotateX(   90deg );
}
.three-d-bullet{
margin:350px 10px 0 0;
float:left;
      position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="three-d-container">
  <input type="radio" checked class="three-d-bullet a" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet b" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet c" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet d" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet e" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet f" name="three-d">
  <div class="three-d-cube">
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/1" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/2" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/3" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/4" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/5" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/6" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: yeah i want this kind of full screen but its not rolling like a dice or cube . when rolling especially 3 and 4 no its not like dice bro see the codepen example i want same things it full screen thanks

Comment: @sayalok https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/eXvmvq check this link. I have also updated my answer. please check. thanks

Comment: really thanks for ur afford but can u make it just full scene

Comment: it to look like a cube it has to be a square. if i take 100% width then height i cannot take 100% it will not remain as square right.. i tried making it full screen but i was not able to achieve what you want. sorry

Comment: yeah you are right, I have also tried lot of time but failed to manage it. its not possible may b . but thanks for your afford

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to use viweport units.

Using vmin you will ensure that the cube is always visible, leaving empty space in the larger viweport dimension.

If you want the other way round, you can use vmax (replace all occurences of vmin with vmax).

```css
.three-d-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 230px;
}

.three-d-cube {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.three-d-cube .three-d-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.three-d-cube .three-d-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(90deg);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform:  translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform:  translateX(-50vmin) rotateY(90deg);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(50vmin) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateY(-50vmin) rotateX( 90deg);
}

.three-d-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(-50vmin) rotateY(90deg);
}

.a:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.b:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(90deg);
}

.c:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.d:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg) rotateY(90deg);
}

.e:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.f:checked~.three-d-cube {
  transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateX(50vmin) rotateY(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

.three-d-bullet {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="three-d-container">
  <input type="radio" checked class="three-d-bullet a" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet b" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet c" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet d" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet e" name="three-d">
  <input type="radio" class="three-d-bullet f" name="three-d">
  <div class="three-d-cube">
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/1" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/2" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/3" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/4" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/5" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="three-d-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/food/6" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```